# npm create-react-app or npx create-react-app is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-install, npm-start

this is the error i got every time
I try all-most everything re-installing npm  re-installing node

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn pwsh
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Dipan\react-data
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn pwsh ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dipan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-10T09_37_51_103Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Do you need help I can connect via google meet

Answer (score 1):

**I solved this using the following command.**

npm uninstall -g create-react-app

**then**
npm install -g create-react-app